# Bash scripting: parameter substitution problem

Tags: bash, command-line, parameters, shell

I'm trying to write a simple bash script but something seems wrong, I'm testing the following on the command line:

```
DATE="2010-09-{10,11}"
result=`\ls *ext.$DATE.Z`
```

and results in ls: cannot access *ext.2010-09-{10,11}.Z: No such file or directory

but if I execute this:

```
result=`\ls *ext.2010-09-{10,11}.Z`
```

it works flawlessly...

I even tried to remove the quotation marks from DATE parameter but that isn't the problem, bash manual isn't helping, what am I doing wrong? Wasn't it supposed to execute parameter substitution and pass it to my command?

I thought I should have to escape the $ sign but that didn't work either.

EDIT - Explanation on purpose added

What I am trying to accomplish is to populate variable *result* with all filenames that match the given pattern (*ext.2010-09-{10,11}), I know I can solve this using a for cycle but I thought about using curly braces for shortness.

Comment: Why are you running it like `\ls`? Aliases do not carry over into the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is when you execute it directly on the command line `\ls *ext.2010-09-{10,11}.Z` is a short form that's expanded into two commands: `ls *ext.2010-09-10.Z` and `ls *ext.2010-09-11.Z` (by the command line - each subsequently called).  `ls` itself doesn't directly support an expression like that, so when you build it into a script, it's getting the literal string which it doesn't understand.

Brace Expansion is not supported by all command lines, and [isn't recommended for shell scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Brace_expansion):

> Brace expansions should not be used in
>   portable shell scripts, because the
>   Bourne shell will not produce the same
>   output.

Here's a solution-script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DAYS="10 11"
for i in $DAYS;
do
  ls *ext.2010-09-$i.Z
done
```

Comment: Correct, your post completes my short explanation. Regards

Comment: But the question is tagged [bash] not [sh] or [bourne] and if you have a shebang that says `#!/bin/bash` you ought to be able to use Bash features.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because brace expansion happens before variable expansion. First it expands the braces -- except there are none in your argument to `ls`. Then it expands the variables. Then it runs it. At this point it's too late to expand the braces.

If you elaborate on the specific problem you're trying to solve I might be able to help you find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The {x,y} group is not expanded anymore if you assign it to a variabile. But you can compose a string like "ls ..." and submit it to the "eval" function.
Bye!

Comment: `eval` is unsafe and could potentially introduce security holes. There's probably a better way

Answer (score 0):

This will put the filenames you're looking for in the variable:

```
result=$(echo *ext.2010-09-{10,11}.Z)
```